# How to disable bold math-mode in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv, boldmath

I am writing a document with the moderncv class

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
```

but I see that all the math-modes are written in bold.
I see that one of the included packages is `bm`, but even removing that nothing changes.
How can I disable this?

Comment: Welcome! We need more information to answer this, could you please turn your `\documentclass` into a small example we can compile

Comment: I can't replicate your setup. Using the (default) [`template.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/template.tex) from [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) (that uses the same `\documentclass` settings you show) and compiling with pdfLaTeX, I get non-bold math as output ([image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuLCJ.png)). Can you provide the community with a minimal document that replicates your issue?

Comment: Never mind, the mistake was actually stupider and I solved it. Apologies for not providing all the necessary items in the first place, it was my first question asked here. Also, thanks for the prompt replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `moderncv` document class includes the `lmodern` package which alters the default math font to appear in bold. To prevent this, use the regular math font instead, you can insert the following code into your preamble (before `\begin{document}`):

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lmr}
```